# URL Rewriteing from dynamic links

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, dynamic

I'm not sure how to re-write a dynamic url into another kind of dynamic url?

I'm looking to change:

```
/blog/category.php?catseourl=ExampleCat&pn=1
/blog/category.php?catseourl=ExampleCat&pn=2
/blog/category.php?catseourl=ExampleCatTwo&pn=1
```

Into:

```
/blog/category/ExampleCat/1
/blog/category/ExampleCat/2
/blog/category/ExampleCatTwo/1
```

I've got to this point:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]*)$ /blog/category.php?catseourl=$1&pn=$1 [L]
```

But I'm not sure how to add the dynamic changes into the left hand side of the rewrite?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog/category.php?catseourl=$1&pn=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Ah thats great! should of realised couldn't have two $1 in the same url. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /blog/category.php?catseourl=$1&pn=$2 [L]
```

Comment: A paragraph (or even a sentence) or two of explanation goes a long way into making a possible correct answer into a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.+)/([0-9]+)$ /blog/category.php?catseourl=$1&pn=$2 [L]
```